# Showing elements of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ can be represented as a nilpotent and a semisimple matrix under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, lie-algebras

I want to use the Jordan form to show that every element $A\in \mathfrak{gl}_n$ can be written as $N+S$ where $N\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is nilpotent and $S\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$ is semisimple and $NS=SN$. Let's put us over $\Bbb C$.

---

Well my first thought is, what does $A\in \mathfrak{gl}_n$ look like? Well they have the commutator as the lie bracket, so $A_1A_2-A_2A_1=0$ I believe and we need all such $A=(A_1A_2-A_2A_1)\in\mathfrak{gl}_n$ I am fairly sure.

Then what is left is to show that $A$ can have some $A_1$ as a nilpotent matrix, and $A_2$ as a semisimple matrix.

Is that what I should do?

Comment: I don't think $A_1 A_2 - A_2 A_1=0$, isn't $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ just all endomorphism between an $n$ dimensional vector space equipped with the commutator Lie bracket. Maybe something was left out or I am misunderstanding what is going on.

Comment: @DiscipleofBarney I am misunderstanding what is going on and that is passing over to you.

I have read two conflicting definitions of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$. One is that it is all $n\times n$ matrices, and another that it is all invertible $n\times n$ matrices. As a lie algebra it seems it must be the former. So I seem to need to just show all $n\times n$ matrices can be constructed by $N+D$ where $N$ and $D$ just hold under the commutator Lie bracket?

Comment: $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is the group of invertible matrices. It basically is a given that $N,S \in \mathfrak{gl}_n$, the only things to show are that there is such a decomposition and that they commute with respect to muliplication (although that is almost just the existence of Jordan form I believe).

Comment: Do you know what Jordan form of a matrix looks like, and do you know what semisimple matrices (especially over $\mathbb{C}$) look like with respect to a nice base? Do you know what nilpotent matrices look like? Try some examples if you don't.

Comment: @DiscipleofBarney Yes to all, but I don't know what a lie bracket actually means, I get how it operates, but I don't know what it actually does

Comment: The lie bracket just means, in this case, $[A,B]=AB-BA$, nothing else. Honestly, the Lie bracket is of no relevance to you in this problem. The existence of such a decomposition is just important in the study of Lie algebras.

Comment: @DiscipleofBarney Wait so any arbitrary $A,B$ in my group has to meet that requirement?

Comment: What requirement?

Comment: @DiscipleofBarney Oh sorry, I thought the lie bracket was $AB-BA=0$ nevermind. Okay I think I am ready to attempt the problem. I will update the question as I progress. Thanks very much

Comment: Oh no, that is not the requirment, that only happens when they commute, so it would be true that $[N,S]=NS-SN=0$ (once you establish they commute).

Comment: @DiscipleofBarney Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the Jordan-Chevalley decomposition of matrices in $M_n(K)$, see wikipedia. Here $K$ is assumed to be a perfect field. Of course, over the complex numbers it holds. Since $M_n(K)$ carries a Lie bracket via $[A,B]=AB-BA$, we can view $M_n(K)$ as the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$.